# How does file_id use in telethon to send a file by a bot?

Tags: python, telethon

To not re-download the file again, I want to send its file_id obtained from a previously sent message.

How does file_id use in telethon to send a file by a bot (not a client):

```
async def main():
    t_client = TelegramClient(TG_APP_TITLE, TG_APP_ID, TG_API_HASH)
    await t_client.connect()
    if not await t_client.is_user_authorized():
        await t_client.send_code_request(TG_PHONE)
        await t_client.sign_in(code=input('Get code:'))

    t_bot = TelegramClient(f'{TG_APP_TITLE}Bot', TG_APP_ID, TG_API_HASH)
    a_bot = aiogram.Bot(TG_BOT_API_TOKEN)

    await t_client.start()
    await t_bot.start(bot_token=TG_BOT_API_TOKEN)

    r = await t_client.send_file(TG_BOT, 'podcasts/gnj2_SB0MOM.100.96.mp3')
    file_id = pack_bot_file_id(r.media)

    await t_client.send_file(TG_CHAT_ID, file_id)  # Correct
    await a_bot.send_audio(TG_CHAT_ID, file_id)  # Correct
    await t_bot.send_file(TG_CHAT_ID, file_id)  # Error
```

When I am trying to send file_id by bot

```
await t_bot.send_file(TG_USER, file_id)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alexo/PycharmProjects/personal/TGVideoToPodcastBot/temp.py", line 76, in main
    await t_bot.send_file(TG_CHAT_ID, file_id)  # Error
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\uploads.py", line 381, in send_file
    return self._get_response_message(request, await self(request), entity)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 79, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.MediaEmptyError: The provided media object is invalid or the current account may not be able to send it (such as games as users) (caused by SendMediaRequest)
```

If I send the file_id through the Bot API (a_bot) or by the client (t_client), then everything is fine.

Comment: `file_id` has some restrictions check this https://docs.pyrogram.org/faq#can-i-use-the-same-file-id-across-different-accounts and also on a side note, I request you to answer your own question to help others. (I see you're a member for 6+ years, so contribute?) if not let me know I will answer this question

Answer (score 1):

```
from telethon.tl.types import InputDocument        
doc = InputDocument(yorfile.id, yorfile.access_hash, yorfile.file_reference)
await client.send_file("@onetimeusername", doc)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.