# telethon : How to save an event and use it later?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

See this :

```
      @bot.on(events.Album())
              async def ene(event):
                          feedBack = await bot.send_message(
                              id,
                              file=event.messages,  # event.messages is a List - meaning we're sending an album
                              message=f"Test",
                              buttons=btn_feed_back 
                          )
                          await save_redis(f"{id}-car-pics", event)
                          await save_redis(f"{id}-status", "wait")
```

In the above code, I save an event in Redis, but I can't use it in other places!!! Do you have a way to save events and use it in the future??

The reason for this issue:

I want to save the addresses of stickers and images without downloading and saving them on the server (because they are uploaded once on the Telegram server and have an access address) in the database and send them to users whenever I want.

Do you have another way to do this? I searched a lot, but I didn't get any results!

Answer (score 0):

```
from telethon.tl.types import InputDocument        
doc = InputDocument(yorfile.id, yorfile.access_hash, yorfile.file_reference)
await client.send_file("@onetimeusername", doc)
```

[find answer in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178276/how-does-file-id-use-in-telethon-to-send-a-file-by-a-bot)